# n-bit ALU in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, alu

I'm making n-bit ALU in scheme and I have a 1-bit ALU so far.
Can someone tell me how to approach this problem? Here are the instructions for it:

> The format of the procedure is
>
> ```
>   (ALUn selection x1 x2 n)
> ```
>
> where the first parameter, `selection` can take any of the values: `'add`, `'sub`, `'and`, `'or`, or `'xor`. The second and third parameters `x1` and `x2` are two n-bit binary numbers in list format.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code for and, or xor:

```
(define (ALUn selection x1 x2 n)
  (cond
    [(or (not (= (length x1) n)) (not (= (length x2) n))) (error "Wrong register length!")]
    [(equal? selection 'and) (map bitwise-and x1 x2)]
    [(equal? selection  'or) (map bitwise-ior x1 x2)]
    [(equal? selection 'xor) (map bitwise-xor x1 x2)]))
```

You should figure how to do add and sub yourself!